# How to change page content based on url search parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, marzipano

I'm working on a project with a large number of 360 images (panoramas) generated from Marzipano tool (https://www.marzipano.net/). I dont want to create a new HTML file for every panorama to be displayed, instead i want to  use a single html file in each directory and change panorama based on URL search id. When a user clicks on a href link, I want to use the search id to dictate which panorama is going to be displayed. I tried to do this using search params in JS, but it doesnt always work correctly or maybe i did something wrong. On some pages, I get a blank screen when i try to display the panorama by clicking on the href link.

index.js

```
    const searchUrl = window.location.search;
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchUrl);
    
      // Display the initial scene.
      searchParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
        switchScene(scenes[value])
        console.log(value, key);
```

HTML href links

```
 

  <area alt="1" coords="134,375,164,405" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=0" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="2" coords="171,355,201,385" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=1" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="3" coords="176,318,206,348" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=2" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="4" coords="177,282,207,312" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=3" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="5" coords="177,247,207,277" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=4" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="6" coords="125,267,155,297" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=5" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="7" coords="77,269,107,299" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=6" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="8" coords="28,265,58,295" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=7" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="9" coords="38,332,68,362" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=8" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
   <area alt="10" coords="87,329,117,359" href="Topside Data\TP35\Main Process Deck Mezz\main-process-deck-mezz.html?id=9" shape="rect" target="_blank"/>
```

HTML where panorama is being display

´´´

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Project Title
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" name="viewport"/>
  <style>
   @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
  </style>
  <link href="vendor/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 <body class="multiple-scenes">
  <div id="pano">
  </div>
  <div id="sceneList">
   <ul class="scenes">
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 1
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-2" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 2
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-3" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 3
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-4" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 4
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-5" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 5
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-6" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 6
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-7" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 7
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main.process-deck-mezz-8" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
      Main Process Deck Mezz 8
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-9" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
       Main Process Deck Mezz 9
     </li>
    </a>
    <a class="scene" data-id="main-process-deck-mezz-10" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <li class="text">
       Main Process Deck Mezz 10
     </li>
    </a>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="titleBar">
   <h1 class="sceneName">
   </h1>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="autorotateToggle">
   <img class="icon off" src="img/play.png"/>
   <img class="icon on" src="img/pause.png"/>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="fullscreenToggle">
   <img class="icon off" src="img/fullscreen.png"/>
   <img class="icon on" src="img/windowed.png"/>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sceneListToggle">
   <img class="icon off" src="img/expand.png"/>
   <img class="icon on" src="img/collapse.png"/>
  </a>
  <a class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-1" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewUp">
   <img class="icon" src="img/up.png"/>
  </a>
  <a class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-2" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewDown">
   <img class="icon" src="img/down.png"/>
  </a>
  <a class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-3" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewLeft">
   <img class="icon" src="img/left.png"/>
  </a>
  <a class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-4" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewRight">
   <img class="icon" src="img/right.png"/>
  </a>
  <a class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-5" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewIn">
   <img class="icon" src="img/plus.png"/>
  </a>
  <a class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-6" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewOut">
   <img class="icon" src="img/minus.png"/>
  </a>
  <script src="vendor/screenfull.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor/bowser.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor/marzipano.js">
  </script>
  <script src="data.js">
  </script>
  <script src="index.js">
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

´´´

[black screen panorama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPsu8.png)

Comment: No images of code please.............

Comment: Try logging searchParams to see if it works as expected